# NHibernate ignores the hbm.xml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate

I added a new table, `.hbm.xml` file and `class` to existing application. There is data from other tables as well displayed on the page.

For this new table data is not saved and displayed.

`NHibernate` ignores it. I don't get any error message. I also change the `table` value in the new `hbm.xml` file, but there is no error. But, if I change `table` in other files, application throws exception. Looks like it is not aware of the new file. I made this file as `Embedded Resource`. I'm using `VS 2010`, `MVC` and `Oracle` and `C#`

And here is the xml and class. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<class name="CaseMgr.Model.BusinessObjects.PatLiverPeld, CaseMgr.Model" table="TGLN.PAT_LIVER_PELD" lazy="true">
  <id name="Id" column="PLP_ID" unsaved-value="0">
    <generator class="sequence">
       <param name="sequence">PLP_SEQ</param>        
    </generator>
 </id>   
<timestamp name="ModifyDate" column="MODIFY_DATE" generated="always"></timestamp>
<property name="CreateDate" column="CREATE_DATE" update="false"></property>
<property name="CreateBy" column="CREATE_BY" update="false" />
<property name="ModifyBy" column="MODIFY_BY" update="false" />
<property name="TestDate" column="PELD_TEST_DATE" />
<property name="ExpDate" column="PELD_EXP_DATE" />
<property name="SerumBilirubin" column="SERUM_BILIRUBIN" />
<property name="Inr" column="INR" />
<property name="Albumin" column="ALBUMIN" />
<property name="GrowthFailure" column="GROWTH_FAILURE" type="YesNo" />
<property name="Peld" column="PELD" />

<many-to-one name="PatRegister" column="PATR_ID" class="PatRegister" />

<bag name="PatLiverSmcs" lazy="true" inverse="true" >
  <key column="PATR_ID"></key>
  <one-to-many class="PatLiverSmc"></one-to-many>
</bag>
<bag name="PatLiverSmcHiss" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" >
  <key column="PATR_ID"></key>
  <one-to-many class="PatLiverSmcHis"></one-to-many>
</bag>
```

```
public partial class PatLiverPeld : BusinessBase<decimal>
{
    private DateTime _createDate = new DateTime();
    private string _createBy =string.Empty;
    private string _modifyBy = string.Empty;
    private DateTime _modifyDate = new DateTime();
    private DateTime? _testDate ;
    private DateTime? _expDate ;
    private double? _serumBilirubin ;
    private double? _inr ;
    private double? _albumin ;
    private bool _growthFailure ;
    private double? _peld ;

    private PatRegister _patRegister = null;

    private IList<PatLiverSmc> _patLiverSmcs = new List<PatLiverSmc>();
    private IList<PatLiverSmcHis> _patLiverSmcHiss = new List<PatLiverSmcHis>();



    public PatLiverPeld(){ }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(this.GetType().FullName);
        sb.Append(_createDate);
        sb.Append(_createBy);
        sb.Append(_modifyBy);
        sb.Append(_modifyDate);
        sb.Append(_testDate);
        sb.Append(_expDate);
        sb.Append(_serumBilirubin);
        sb.Append(_inr);            
        sb.Append(_albumin);
        sb.Append(_growthFailure);
        sb.Append(_peld);
        return sb.ToString().GetHashCode();            
    }



    public virtual DateTime CreateDate 
    {
        get { return _createDate; }
        set { _createDate = value; } 
    }

    public virtual string CreateBy 
    {
        get { return _createBy; }
        set { _createBy = value; } 
    }

    public virtual string ModifyBy 
    {
        get { return _modifyBy; }
        set { _modifyBy = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime ModifyDate 
    {
        get { return _modifyDate; }
        set { _modifyDate = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime? TestDate 
    {
        get { return _testDate; }
        set { _testDate = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime? ExpDate 
    {
        get { return _expDate; }
        set { _expDate = value; }

    }


    public virtual double? SerumBilirubin 
    {
        get { return _serumBilirubin; }
        set { _serumBilirubin = value; }

    }

    public virtual double? Inr
    {
        get { return _inr; }
        set { _inr = value; }
    }

    public virtual double? Albumin 
    {
        get { return _albumin; }
        set { _albumin = value; } 
    }

    public virtual bool GrowthFailure 
    {
        get { return _growthFailure; }
        set { _growthFailure = value; }
    }

    public virtual double? Peld
    {
        get { return _peld; }
        set { _peld = value; }

    }


    public virtual PatRegister PatRegister
    {
        get { return _patRegister; }
        set { _patRegister = value; }
    }

    public virtual IList<PatLiverSmc> PatLiverSmcs
    {
        get { return _patLiverSmcs; }
        set { _patLiverSmcs = value; }

    }

    public virtual IList<PatLiverSmcHis> PatLiverSmcHiss 
    {
        get { return _patLiverSmcHiss; }
        set { _patLiverSmcHiss = value; }
    }

    public virtual bool IsDataExpired
    {
        get
        {
            return (ExpDate.HasValue && ExpDate.Value <= DateTime.Today);
        }
    }

    //public virtual bool IsPatPeld
    //{
    //    get { return this.PatRegister.Pat.Age <= LiverSmcConst.PAEDIATRIC_PELD_AGE; }
    //}
}
```

`Web.Config`

```
 <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
 <session-factory>

   <property name="connection.provider">CaseMgr.Web.Dao.SvcConnectionProvider,CaseMgr.Web</property>
  <!--<property name="connection.provider">CaseMgr.Model.Base.NHConnectionProvider, CaseMgr.Model</property>-->
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string_name">OraConnStr</property>
  <property name="show_sql">false</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>
  <property name="query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</property>
  <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">CaseMgr.OracleCache.OraCacheProvider, CaseMgr.OracleCache</property>
  <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
  <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
   <mapping assembly="CaseMgr.Model" />
  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Are you REALLY sure that the hbm file is set to Embedded Resource?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. To make sure, I put other value and I got the exception. I'm really clueless

Comment: Does your config file have a `<mapping assembly="CaseMgr.Model" />` in it? Please post your config file relating to nHibernate, ta

Comment: I added the web.config

Comment: Do you have more hbm.xml files in your sln? If so do they work as intended?

Comment: So the verdict is, I created a new project and added new objects one by one to test. And it worked. And then I copied same files to the actual project. Problem solved!! The current project is too big. So, it is possible that I may have messed up something.

Comment: MY APOLOGY TO THE COMMUNITY

Answer (score 2):

The similar issue as you, I have faced recently. And it was in VS 2012, where file re-naming works like, 1) selecting *.hbm.xml* file by clicking on it... 2) the part before file suffix is selected. 3) type new name, while suffix is unchanged.

The trick is that NHibernate files, *embedded resources*, have two suffixes: .hbm.xml. The configuration like this:

```
<mapping assembly="CaseMgr.Model" />
```

Works with convention: search embedded resources with the extension **.hbm.xml**. So, if your new file is

- MyNewFile.xml

It must be

- MyNewfile **.hbm.** xml

the missing **.hbm** was in my case the reason, why NHibernate did not know about that file at all, and no exception was thrown if it was wrong... but it was not loaded and not available

EXTENDED

If I get your scenario correctly: One VS project(library), many .hbm.xml files, all are embedded resources, all are working but one.

If I reproduce your issue correctly you should:

run IL Spy to check that the dll contains all expected embedded resources
run a test like:

```
var factory = ... //get your NHibernate factory
var entityType = typeof(CaseMgr.Model.BusinessObjects.PatLiverPeld);
var persister = factory.GetClassMetadata(entityType) as AbstractEntityPersister;
Assert.IsTrue(persister != null)
```

In case that you'll see resource, and there is NO persister... try to move your mapping to existing working file (two classes in one .hbm.xml file). Any other case could hardly happen, because of missing exceptions during the "worng" config class mappings (as stated in the question)

Comment: It has .hbm.xml extension

Comment: I've updated the answer, expecting that I do understand your scenario. please correct me if wrong