# NHibernate searches for wrong filename

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm new to nhibernate and tried a few tutorials but none of them helped with that problem:

I did my mappings, classes, ... and when I'm trying to add my class to configuration, hibernate is searching for the wrong filename (I guess in the wrong directory).

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20170915093558.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20170915093558;Integrated Security=True</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <mapping assembly="WebApplication1"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

This is my `Test`-entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="WebApplication1"
                   namespace="WebApplication1.Domain">

  <class name="Test" table="Test" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="DatasetCreationDate" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>

namespace WebApplication1.Domain
{
    public class Test
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DatasetCreationDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm now calling:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
configuration.AddClass(typeof(Test));
configuration.Configure();
SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

On this line I get following error by nhibernate:

```
configuration.AddClass(typeof(Test));
```

> Resource not found: WebApplication1.Domain.Test.hbm.xml

This is my structure:

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong here? I think my file-structure is also wrong.

Comment: Double check all `hbm.xml` files and their **Build action** property - to be `Embeded resource` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139805/1679310

Comment: *That makes sense.. we all (almost) were there ;)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the problems myself (with a bit of help by Radim Köhler):

**1st problem**

The properties for the `.hbm.xml`-files

- Build Action: `Embedded Resource`.
- Copy to Output Directory: `Do not copy`

**2nd problem**

I was adding the assembly twice.

- Once in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`: `<mapping assembly="WebApplication1"/>`
- and once when building the session factory: `configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());`

I now deleted the one in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`